# Autocomplete for titles via ajax - rework of past post away from like_escape()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create an input field that can autocomplete only title from a CPT. They don't have to be linked, they just need to pull titles of a cpt alphabetically and searching from the first letters.

I found a great post on the stackexchange, but it is old and it uses like_escape() which is deprecated. I understand you should now use  esc_like() . I was hoping that someone can point me in the right direction in how to transition from like_escape() to esc_like() from the code below   ?

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_wp_enqueue_scripts');
function se_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('suggest');
}

add_action('wp_head', 'se_wp_head');
function se_wp_head() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var se_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#se_search_element_id').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup');
});
</script>

<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');

function se_lookup() {
global $wpdb;

$search = like_escape($_REQUEST['q']);

$query = 'SELECT ID,post_title FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . '
    WHERE post_title LIKE \'' . $search . '%\'
    AND post_type = \'post_type_name\'
    AND post_status = \'publish\'
    ORDER BY post_title ASC';
foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query) as $row) {
    $post_title = $row->post_title;
    $id = $row->ID;

    $meta = get_post_meta($id, 'YOUR_METANAME', TRUE);

    echo $post_title . ' (' . $meta . ')' . "\n";
}
die();
}
```

Original post and credit to the following:

[Auto-complete or auto-suggest from list of post titles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58576/auto-complete-or-auto-suggest-from-list-of-post-titles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute `$search = like_escape($_REQUEST['q']);` with

```
$search = $wpdb->esc_like( $_REQUEST['q'] );
```

(Note assuming `$_REQUEST` has standard WP magic_quotes_gpc escaping.)

For reference, here's the exact code I put in "functions.php":

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_wp_enqueue_scripts');
function se_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('suggest');
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'se_wp_head');
function se_wp_head() {
?>
Search: <input id="se_search_element_id" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
var se_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#se_search_element_id').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup', {minchars:1});
});
</script>

<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');

function se_lookup() {
    global $wpdb;

    $search = $wpdb->esc_like($_REQUEST['q']);

    $query = 'SELECT ID,post_title FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . '
        WHERE post_title LIKE \'' . $search . '%\'
        AND post_type = \'post\'
        AND post_status = \'publish\'
        ORDER BY post_title ASC';
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post_title = $row->post_title;
        $id = $row->ID;
        echo $post_title, "\n";
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Note the suggestion box just comes up as a list so would need some styling...

Comment: Do I need the strip slashes in the query with "LIKE" and the other query variables?

Comment: No, I see what you're saying - so my saying to use `esc_sql()` (and dig at original answer) is wrong as the query vars will already be escaped - will update answer (which is now just a straight swop)...

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answer. I was hoping that changing from the deprecated function would get this working for me, but alas...Unless im misunderstanding this, can't I get this to work on a standard input with an ID of se_search_element_id and a name of q?

Comment: Okay, ta, just tried it - the name of the input doesn't need to be `q`, `q` is set internally by suggest, just the id of the input needs to be `se_search_element_id` - "works for me", though for ease of testing I used `wp_footer`, not `wp_head`, and I just returned the `$post_title`, no meta, and set the `minchars` option to 1 via `jQuery('#se_search_element_id').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup', {minchars:1});` but I don't think any of those changes really matter...

Comment: Added test code to answer for your reference...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code indeed works! Oddly, my code because I have the <input> in a page template doesn't. It must be where the suggest jquery is being called. I will play with it. It's only a matter of time now : ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31329/discussion-between-work-together2013-and-bonger).